# Using pandas to sum columns based on a criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use pandas to group sales information based on category and a criteria.
For example in "Table 1" below, I want sales totals for each category excluding those with a "Not Stated" in the Reg/Org column.   My ideal output would be in "Table 2" below.   My actual data set has 184 columns, and I am trying to capture the sales volume by category across any values excluding those that are "Not Stated".

Thank you for any help or direction that you can provide.

TABLE 1

| Category | Reg/Org | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Regular | 10 |
| Apple | Organic | 5 |
| Apple | Not Stated | 5 |
| Banana | Regular | 15 |
| Banana | Organic | 5 |

TABLE 2

| Category | Reg/Org |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 15 |
| Banana | 20 |

The first part was to summarize the values by column for the entire data set. I utilized the code below to gather that info for each of the 184 columns. Now I want to create a further summary where I create those column totals again, but split by the 89 categories I have. Ideally, I am trying to create a cross tab, where the categories are listed down the rows, and each of the 184 columns contains the sales. (e.g. the column "Reg/Org" would no longer show "Organic" or "Regular", it would just show the sales volume for all values that are not "Not Stated".)

```
att_list = att.columns.tolist() 
ex_list = ['NOT STATED','NOT COLLECTED'] 
sales_list = [] 
for att_col in att_list:
    sales_list.append(att[~att[att_col].isin(ex_list)]['$'].sum())
```

Comment: Do you have any snippet of code showing what you tried ? And do you want to groupby Reg/Org as well or do you want to drop this column?

Comment: Yes, so my first part was to summarize the values by column for the entire data set.  I utilized the code below to gather that info for each of the 184 columns.   Now I want to create a further summary where I create those column totals again, but split by the 89 categories I have.   Ideally, I am trying to create a cross tab, where the categories are listed down the rows, and each column contains the sales.
att_list = att.columns.tolist()
ex_list = ['NOT STATED','NOT COLLECTED']

sales_list = []
for att_col in att_list:
    sales_list.append(att[~att[att_col].isin(ex_list)]['$'].sum())

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df[df["Reg/Org"]!="Not Stated"].groupby("Category").sum()
```

Or

```
df.groupby("Category").sum().drop(index= ["Not Stated"])
```

Answer (score 0):

try using "YourDataframe.loc[]" with a filter inside

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('Test_excel.xlsx')
sales_volum = data.loc[data["Reg/Org"] != "Not Stated"]
print(str(sales_volum))
```